# Seaborn scatterplot legend showing true values and normalized continuous color

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that I'd like to use to build a scatterplot where different points have different colors:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dat=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 2), columns=['x','y'])
dat['c']=np.random.randint(0,100,20)
dat['c_norm']=(dat['c']-dat['c'].min())/(dat['c'].max()-dat['c'].min())
dat['group']=np.append(np.repeat('high',10), np.repeat('low',10))
```

[image]

As you can see, the column `c_norm` shows the `c` column has been normalized between 0 and 1. I would like to show a continuous legend whose color range reflect the normalized values, but labeled using the original `c` values as label. Say, the minimum (`1`), the maximum (`86`), and the median (`49`). I also want to have differing markers depending on `group`.

So far I was able to do this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 

for row in dat.index:
    if(dat.loc[row,'group']=='low'):
        i_marker='.'
    else:
        i_marker='x'

    ax.scatter(
        x=dat.loc[row,'x'],
        y=dat.loc[row,'y'],
        s=50, alpha=0.5,
        marker=i_marker
    )
    ax.legend(dat['c_norm'], loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 0.5), ncol=1)
```

[image]

Questions:
   - How to generate a continuous legend based on the values?
   - How to adapt its ticks to show the original ticks in `c`, or at least a `min`, `max`, and `mean` or `median`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact that you ask for something continuous makes me want to suggest you to use a colorbar. Would that fit your needs?

Comment: @Patol75 yes, that would work! My only concern then is that I still need to distinguish between the two types of markers (dots and crosses, for `dat['group']`)

Comment: I've also added the code I used to generate the figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer. Do you actually need to determine your marker colors based on the normed values? See the output of the snippet below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])
dat['c'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 20)
dat['c_norm'] = (dat['c'] - dat['c'].min()) / (dat['c'].max() - dat['c'].min())
dat['group'] = np.append(np.repeat('high', 10), np.repeat('low', 10))
fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, num=0, figsize=(16, 8))
mask = dat['group'] == 'low'
scat = ax.scatter(dat['x'][mask], dat['y'][mask], s=50, c=dat['c'][mask],
                  marker='s', vmin=np.amin(dat['c']), vmax=np.amax(dat['c']),
                  cmap='plasma')
ax.scatter(dat['x'][~mask], dat['y'][~mask], s=50, c=dat['c'][~mask],
           marker='X', vmin=np.amin(dat['c']), vmax=np.amax(dat['c']),
           cmap='plasma')
cbar = fig.colorbar(scat, ax=ax)
scat = bx.scatter(dat['x'][mask], dat['y'][mask], s=50, c=dat['c_norm'][mask],
                  marker='s', vmin=np.amin(dat['c_norm']),
                  vmax=np.amax(dat['c_norm']), cmap='plasma')
bx.scatter(dat['x'][~mask], dat['y'][~mask], s=50, c=dat['c_norm'][~mask],
           marker='X', vmin=np.amin(dat['c_norm']),
           vmax=np.amax(dat['c_norm']), cmap='plasma')
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(scat, ax=bx)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You could definitely modify the second colorbar so that it matches the first one, but is that necessary?